# Sublime text 3 Find in flies

Tags: sublime-text-3

В `sublime text 3` по `ctrl-shift-f` нет поля для замены. Как заменить в нескольких файлах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ctrl+H вроде , у меня так

Comment: @geyan ctrl+h для замены в текущем файле. А мне надо список файлов

Comment: Сделал у себя сработало, может клавиши изменили? Пункт меню Find / FInd in Files... работает?

Comment: @Herrgott про список не знаю - к сожалению

Comment: @fermeg работает, может тема виновата, ща проверю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое случается с темой Boxy. Надо просто потянуть вверх за верхний край формы.

Comment: И точно. Спасибо!

Comment: Yus, // 1) Разрабы накосячили с последним обновлением темы. — Можете сказать, какой темы? У автора вопроса не дефолтная. Вы имеете такую же? 2) последним обновлением — я не думаю, что к проблеме как-то причастны последние обновления. Если можно, ответьте, воспроизводится ли проблема на предыдущих версиях. // Раз данное решение подошло, полагаю, что скорее всего причина в старинном баге (см., например, [**здесь**](https://github.com/born2c0de/Incrementor/issues/2): при изменении размера шрифта панели Find in Files и Find and Replace приходится разворачивать/сворачивать вручную.

Comment: Да, есть плагин [**RevertFontSize**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RevertFontSize). Если понадобилось изменить размер шрифта, командой Revert Font Size он быстро откатывается к заданному в настройках. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос, кэп. Да, у меня стоит Boxy Tomorrow. И да, после того, как недавно прилетело крупное обновление, я тоже наткнулся на описываемый автором баг. Более того, после предложенных мной манипуляций (лично у меня) данный баг больше не повторяется.

Comment: *обновление темы, не сублима.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в ответ дополнительную информацию из комментариев. (И Boxy один человек разрабатывает). Спасибо.

Comment: И судя по вашей реакции, этот человек — вы? :) Смысл мне добавлять всё это в ответ, если это мало относится к решению проблемы? Вопрос был не «кто виноват», а «что делать». Boxy остаётся одной из лучших тем, которые я пробовал на сублиме. А косяки бывают у всех. Что вас так задевает?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46958/discussion-between---and-yus).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в теме `Boxy`. Отключил - всё появилось

Comment: **Не воспроизводится** на любой из тем Boxy. И я заглянул в настройки Boxy — панель Find in Files там ничего не должно ломать. Возможно, Ваш ответ бесполезен для других пользователей. // Пожалуйста, скачайте новый Sublime Text для своей операционной системы (удалять в прежней ничего не нужно; если у Вас Windows — скачайте portable версию) и в этой новой версии попробуйте открыть панель Find in Files без Boxy и c Boxy. Спасибо.

Comment: Не закрыли - значит не бесполезен. @YuS дал верный ответ

Comment: **1)** Не закрыли - значит не бесполезен. — Ответы не закрывают. Более того, их не удаляют по причине неправильности. Минус за это крайне некорректное на мой взгляд заключение из посылки. // **2)** @YuS дал верный ответ — я не уверен в этом полностью. Во всяком случае, в ответе мало деталей, чтобы можно было бы воспроизвести проблему. // Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, не уверен в чём? Я написал что надо сделать, чтобы появилось поле для замены, Herrgott сделал, всё получилось. Это не ответ на вопрос? В чём проблема с ответом, кроме ущемлённой гордости?

Comment: @YuS, все аргументы я описал в комментариях к Вашему ответу. Пожалуйста, не надо приписывать мне скрытые мотивы («задевает», «ущемлённой гордости»). Спасибо.